# SFTP - client-side error possible even if server has successfully written file?

Tags: sftp

Is there any reason to be worried about the possibility that upon attempting to upload a file via SFTP, the server successfully writes out the file but then the connection with the client breaks before any confirmation is sent back, hence the client is left not knowing whether the file was uploaded successfully?
The contents of the file are such that it's vital the client knows for sure that it was written out in full. To be certain, is it best to re-attempt connecting to the server and confirm if the file was written in full? Or should I be able to trust that the client-side library would do this for me?

Comment: *before any confirmation is sent back* - Confirmation of what? - *Or should I be able to trust that the client-side library would do this for me?* - Do what? - Your question is sooo vague! What client library are you using? = What's your API? You are implementing the client, right?

Comment: Actually I answered my own question. Basically I compiled my own SSH/SFTP server that deliberately killed the process as soon the file upload was complete. When the client tried to upload the file an exception was thrown that is indistinguishable from one that might be thrown if the file had never been fully written. So I guess if I want genuinely robust behavior I need to be able to cope with this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just possible, this is observed from time to time (mostly with misconfigured servers). So your client should be ready to track its latest operation, and if it was eg. file upload, then the client would need to reconnect and check if the file is on the server, and has the expected size and date. On the other hand, such scenario can fail in cases when the server moves away the file right after upload completion (usually for processing).

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up changing my code to do (more or less) - basically when it does retry after an error, it allows for the possibility that the expected file is already there and treats it as a non error. In my case I can be certain that file won't be moved away until some time later.